# Making Bootstrap's modal-fullscreen not quite fullscreen

Tags: bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5, bootstrap5-modal

I needed a way to create fullscreen Bootstrap modals that weren't 'fully' fullscreen, as I felt that this may create the impression of the site having navigated to a new page. The solution seemed to be to rework the existing `modal-fullscreen` to pull it in a bit at the edges. I couldn't find an existing solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a go at custom CSS for this. Not sure how robust it is but I didn't change a lot from `modal-fullscreen`.

```
.modal-almost-fullscreen {
    width: 99vw;
    max-width: none;
    height: 99%;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
  }
  .modal-almost-fullscreen .modal-content {
    height: 99%;
    border: 0;
  }
  .modal-almost-fullscreen .modal-header,
  .modal-almost-fullscreen .modal-footer {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  .modal-almost-fullscreen .modal-body {
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
  
  @media (max-width: 575.99px) {
    .modal-almost-fullscreen-sm-down {
      width: 99vw;
      max-width: none;
      height: 99%;
      margin: 0;
    }
    .modal-almost-fullscreen-sm-down .modal-content {
      height: 99%;
      border: 0;
      border-radius: 0;
    }
    .modal-almost-fullscreen-sm-down .modal-header,
  .modal-almost-fullscreen-sm-down .modal-footer {
      border-radius: 0;
    }
    .modal-almost-fullscreen-sm-down .modal-body {
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 767.99px) {
    .modal-almost-fullscreen-md-down {
      width: 99vw;
      max-width: none;
      height: 99%;
      margin: 0;
    }
    .modal-almost-fullscreen-md-down .modal-content {
      height: 99%;
      border: 0;
      border-radius: 0;
    }
    .modal-almost-fullscreen-md-down .modal-header,
  .modal-almost-fullscreen-md-down .modal-footer {
      border-radius: 0;
    }
    .modal-almost-fullscreen-md-down .modal-body {
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 991.99px) {
    .modal-almost-fullscreen-lg-down {
      width: 99vw;
      max-width: none;
      height: 99%;
      margin: 0;
    }
    .modal-almost-fullscreen-lg-down .modal-content {
      height: 99%;
      border: 0;
      border-radius: 0;
    }
    .modal-almost-fullscreen-lg-down .modal-header,
  .modal-almost-fullscreen-lg-down .modal-footer {
      border-radius: 0;
    }
    .modal-almost-fullscreen-lg-down .modal-body {
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 1199.99px) {
    .modal-almost-fullscreen-xl-down {
      width: 99vw;
      max-width: none;
      height: 99%;
      margin: 0;
    }
    .modal-almost-fullscreen-xl-down .modal-content {
      height: 99%;
      border: 0;
      border-radius: 0;
    }
    .modal-almost-fullscreen-xl-down .modal-header,
  .modal-almost-fullscreen-xl-down .modal-footer {
      border-radius: 0;
    }
    .modal-almost-fullscreen-xl-down .modal-body {
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 1399.99px) {
    .modal-almost-fullscreen-xxl-down {
      width: 99vw;
      max-width: none;
      height: 99%;
      margin: 0;
    }
    .modal-almost-fullscreen-xxl-down .modal-content {
      height: 99%;
      border: 0;
      border-radius: 0;
    }
    .modal-almost-fullscreen-xxl-down .modal-header,
  .modal-almost-fullscreen-xxl-down .modal-footer {
      border-radius: 0;
    }
    .modal-almost-fullscreen-xxl-down .modal-body {
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
  }
```

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/valoukh/e2karuxf/